# Using a custom backend in addiotion to a headless cms overkill?

Tags: architecture, strapi, headless-cms

I am going to create a website that uses a headless cms for easy entering and admin of data, [Strapi](https://strapi.io) is the preferred choice. For authentication and authorization I am thinking to use a separate backend so that the frontend will communicate solely with my backend that in turns get data from the cms.

Is this unnecessarily complicated? Bad practice?

User <--> Frontend <--> Backend <--> Headless cms <--> Admin UI

Answer (score 0):

Opinion questions aren't really welcome on stack overflow.

And there is nothing can be answered without knowing why exactly (auth type, providers, strapi can't handle) would you need extra backend layer since `strapi` already provides `user-permissons` plugin, used for auth... And there is already stuff like `providers` for auth...

In any case, the problem here is not `is it good?` or `is it bad?` to add a backend layer, but real problem is maintain the code base after you add it...

Personally i doubt you have case that you `need` extra layer, and even more i doubt that you can't extend `strapi` that way to add what's you missing...

Comment: Hi. I realize this is opinion based. Thanks for advice regarding providers for auth and extension of Strapi, this had crossed my mind, but I wan't to avoid being "locked in" to a certain way of doing anything beyond headless cms/data delivery.